# Getting first and last week in an month

Tags: php, date

I have been trying to find the first and last week in an month with strtotime

```
$year = 2013;
$month = 12;

$first_week = date("W", strtotime('first week '.$year.'-'.$month));
$last_week = date("W", strtotime('last week '.$year.'-'.$month));
```

Result:

```
$first_week = 49
$last_week = 47
```

Strange result, how to get the right results?

Comment: You'll have to define "week of the month" first. Is it the week in which the first of the month is in, or the first full week?

Comment: Yes it is the week in which the first of the month is in

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "the week in which the first and last of the month is in", just use those dates:

```
date("W", strtotime("2013-12-01"));
date("W", strtotime("2013-12-31"));
```

So, in your case:

```
$year = 2013;
$month = 12;
$daysinmonth = date("t", strtotime("$year-$month"));

$firstweek = date("W", strtotime("$year-$month-01"));
$lastweek = date("W", strtotime("$year-$month-$daysinmonth"));
```

Comment: $year and $month are variables.

Comment: @Multer, it should be easy to make them variables. There is also a "number of days in month" format specifier.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer no, but you can find it out (I updated my question).

Comment: When I echo in your example $first_week; = 48 $last_week; = 01

Comment: @Mutter, which is correct. 2013-12-31 is in week 01 of 2014. You can use `o` to get the year to which the week belongs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$year = 2013;
$month = 12;

$first_day = strtotime("first day of " . $year . "-" . $month);
$last_day = strtotime("last day of " . $year . "-" . $month);

$first_week = date("W", $first_day);
$last_week = date("W", $last_day);
```

or

```
$year = 2013;
$month = 12;

$last_day = date("t", strtotime($year . "-" . $month));

$first_week = date("W", strtotime($year . "-" . $month . "-01"));
$last_week = date("W", strtotime($year . "-" . $month . "-" . $last_day));
```

Comment: When I echo in your example
$first_week; = 49
$last_week; = 48

Comment: Well I tested it locally on my machine and on http://writecodeonline.com/php/. Both say 48/01 which is correct.